# How to resolve this syntax error in a postgresql sql query to update multiple rows in a single column

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

Given the `tableA` in a Postgres database, I need to update multiple rows in the field `column_a`:

```
UPDATE tableA
SET
  column_a = CASE WHEN column_a = 'conserve' THEN column_a = 'fixed',
  column_a = CASE WHEN column_a = 'balance' THEN column_a = 'moderate',
  column_a = CASE WHEN column_a = 'balance growth' THEN column_a = 'moderate growth',
  column_a = CASE WHEN column_a = 'aggressive' THEN column_a = 'moderate/agressive';
```

but I'm getting the following syntax error:

> Error: syntax error at or near ","

Comment: You are missing the `END`: `CASE..WHEN..THEN..END`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with one single `CASE` statement:

```
UPDATE tableA
SET
  column_a = CASE WHEN column_a = 'conserve'       THEN 'fixed'
                  WHEN column_a = 'balance'        THEN 'moderate'
                  WHEN column_a = 'balance growth' THEN 'moderate growth'  
                  WHEN column_a = 'aggressive'     THEN 'moderate/agressive'
             END;
```

Try it [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=0ca0deb5516ffedad39cae4afe47cfad).