# How to rewrite this sql query, that updates multiple rows in a single column, WITHOUT using CASE

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

I am working on a new project and am trying to update multiple rows in a single column.  It appears any query using the CASE syntax is throwing an error.  I am needing to rewrite this query so that the CASE syntax is not used.  Any help here is appreciated, i have:

```
UPDATE tableA
SET
  column_a = CASE WHEN column_a = 'conserve'       THEN 'fixed'
                  WHEN column_a = 'balance'        THEN 'mod'
                  WHEN column_a = 'balance growth' THEN 'mod growth'  
                  WHEN column_a = 'aggressive'     THEN 'mod/agressive'
             END;
```

The error I am seeing in our pipleine is:

```
Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ERROR: syntax at or near "column_a"
```

I am looking for alternatives to using CASE when updating multiple rows in a single column.

Comment: The syntax is correct. Please **[edit]** your question and add the **exact** and complete error message you get

Comment: Isn't this the code from the answer that you accepted as correct in your previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72260608/how-to-resolve-this-syntax-error-in-a-postgresql-sql-query-to-update-multiple-ro

Comment: It is, but this is a new question, the code is correct, i am trying to refactor it without the CASE syntax

Comment: If it is correct why do you say in your question that there is an error?

Comment: I'm looking for alternative syntax for various reasons.  The code you provided was fine for that answer thanks. This is a new question unfortunately with a different ask.

Comment: @ghostagent151 Do my examples from the answer below suit you or do you need more variation?

Comment: perfect, ty jesusbrother, the alternatives work. the fiddle provided was also great ty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what a reason to not use CASE (coz imo it's a more useful option), but [here's dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=5104d274fa85cfd12dd48d81ab48be83) with a couple of alternatives for the UPDATE statement (REPLACE and CTE):

```
-- replace example
    UPDATE tableA
    SET
        column_a = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE
        (column_a, 'conserve', 'fixed'),
        'balance', 'moderate'),
        'aggressive','moderate/agressive');

-- CTE example
UPDATE tableA
SET
    column_a = tmp.tmp_val
FROM (
SELECT 'conserve' as tmp_key, 'fixed' as tmp_val
union select 'balance', 'moderate'
union select 'balance growth', 'moderate growth'
union select 'aggressive', 'moderate/agressive'
) tmp
WHERE tmp.tmp_key = tableA.column_a
;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would write this query like as follows. It's not pritty but should get the job done.

```
UPDATE tableA
SET column_a = REPLACE(column_a, 'conserve', 'fixed'),
column_a = REPLACE(column_a, 'balance', 'moderate'),
...
```

Comment: This is not valid code for Postgresql.